# How to add a button into a groupbox dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I am dynamically trying to add a button inside a groupbox, however the button stays behind the groupbox tool and can not be seen or can not be clicked. I need my button to be seen and clickable inside of the groupbox. Here is my code:

```
namespace HarryPotter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            GroupBox grp = new GroupBox();
            grp.Top = 600;
            grp.Left = 0;
            grp.Text = "Kontroller";
            grp.Size = new Size(600, 400);
            //grp.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.hogwartscastle;
            //grp.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            grp.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Controls.Add(grp);

            Button btn2 = new Button();
            btn2.Size = new Size(40, 40);
            btn2.Top = 580;
            btn2.Left = 0;
            btn2.Parent = grp;
            btn2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\DownArrow.png");
            btn2.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            grp.Controls.Add(btn2);
            this.Controls.Add(btn2);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Remove `this.Controls.Add(btn2);`. You have added the button to the  GroupBox using: `grp.Controls.Add(btn2);`, then you have added the button the Form using `this.Controls.Add(btn2);`, which removes it from GroupBox, because a control can have only one parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `GroupBox` is only 400 pixels tall but the `Button` has its top at y location 580.  So the button is there but its not visible. So either make the groupbox taller or change the `btn2.Top`.  Also you need to create the Click event handler for `btn2` with the following: `btn2.Click += Btn2_Click` then define the `Btn2_Click` function.

**Edit**: as Reza pointed out, you need to remove the `this.Controls.Add(btn2);` line as well since that will remove the button from the group box.